# Python super: base class method calls another method

Tags: python, super

I came across this unexpected behavior using Python `super`, so I thought I would ask. I am aware of basic `super` usage but would like someone to elaborate more on my problem here. Consider the code:

```
class Base (object):
    def f1 (self):
        print 'Base f1'

    def f2 (self):
        print 'Base f2'
        self.f1()

class Derived (Base):
    def f1 (self):
        print 'Derived f1'

    def f2 (self):
        print 'Derived f2'
        super(Derived, self).f2()
```

The call to Derived().f2() results in:

```
Derived f2
Base f2
Derived f1
```

I was rather expecting:

```
Derived f2
Base f2
Base f1
```

Shouldn't the call "self.f1()" in Base.f2() result in Base.f1() being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` in all cases is *still the `Derived` instance*.

`super()` finds the overriden method and *binds it to `self`*, you are *not* swapping out classes. `super(Derived, self).f2` finds the next `f2` method on the `Base` class, and binds that to `self`. When called then, `self` is still the same instance, and calling `f1` on `self` will invoke `Derived.f1`.

Comment: I see. Is there more documentation around this behavior that you are aware of? Thanks.

Comment: There is the [`super()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) (for attribute lookup information and how method binding works), and the [Method Resolution Order description](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) to in what order `super()` will scan for names to bind. I've also [written extensively on `super()` here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+super+mro).