# Python super: calling a base class method which contains another base class method that is overriden by derived class

Tags: python

```py
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "A - foo"
    def foo2(self):
        print "foo2"
        self.foo()

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print "B - foo"
    def foo2(self):
        super(B, self).foo2()

B().foo2()
```

I was trying to get [senario1]:

```
foo2
A - foo
```

but got [senario2]:

```
foo2
B - foo
```

instead.

I found [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097205/python-super-base-class-method-calls-another-method), but I am wondering if there is a way that yields [senario1] without changing the name of method `foo` in class `A`?

Comment: You can change `A.foo2` so that it explicitly calls `A.foo(self)`, but that's not really a good solution. I think the most proper fix would be to change the name of `B.foo`. If it's not supposed to override `A.foo` then, well, don't override `A.foo`.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you'll say inside `B.foo2` something like `self.__class__ = A` and then call `self.foo2()` and then again `self.__class__ = B`. In a simple example I've tested this worked as expected and might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to call `foo` on `A` and pass `self` to it by hand:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("A - foo")
    def foo2(self):
        print("foo2")
        A.foo(self)

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("B - foo")
    def foo2(self):
        super(B, self).foo2()

B().foo2()
```

This way you will always call `foo` on `A`. If this `foo` would call `self.foo()`, if would again call `B`s foo method.

Answer (score 1):

As Leon pointed out you could simply access the `foo` method inside the `A` class by hardcoding the explicit call via `A.foo` and passing instance object as argument, however as Rawing has stated it's not good solution. Actually it's example of wrong class design. Why?

1. Imagine that in a larger project you would use explicit calls via `A.foo` in hundreds of places. Now, try to rename your `A` class to `MagicUnicorn` class.
2. It's counter-intuitive. If you override the `foo` method from `A` in `B` then the `foo` from `A` is not needed in 99.9999% cases as there must be a reason to override it.

A better solution rather than using explicit calls would be to rename the `foo` in `B` (as Rawing has said):

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "A - foo"
    def foo2(self):
        print "foo2"
        self.foo()

class B(A):
    def unicorn_foo(self):
        print "B - foo"
    def foo2(self):
        super(B, self).foo2()

B().foo2()
```